Cloud Watch Log Insights
I have a message stating : "Method taking x time"
The below query gives me all the logs starting with Method taking.
fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream, @log 
| filter @message like /Method taking/
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 1000

Is there a way to grab us the time value from the message and build a graph using it, to find max, min, average.

You'll want to use parse to extract data from the message and then do logic on the resulting numerical value, e.g. using stats.
